# For operator $P_{t}$ if $0\leq f \leq 1$ implies $0\leq P_{t}f \leq 1$ then $\lvert \lvert P_{t}f\rvert \rvert \leq \lvert \lvert f\rvert \rvert$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, inequality, stochastic-processes

For operator a linear $P_{t}:C_{0}(\mathbb R)\to C_{0}(\mathbb R)$ if $0\leq f \leq 1$ implies $0\leq P_{t}f \leq 1$ then we obtain $\lvert \lvert P_{t}f\rvert \rvert \leq \lvert \lvert f\rvert \rvert$

My attempt (I am struggling with the negative cases especially):

Consider $f\in C_{0}(\mathbb R)$ and further $f = f_{+}-f_{-}$ be the decomposition into positive and negative parts:

Case 1: Assume that $P_{t}f(x) \geq 0$:

Case 1.1 Assume that $f(x)=f_{+}(x)\geq 0$, then

$0\leq P_{t}f(x)=P_{t}f_{+}(x)=\lvert \lvert f \rvert \rvert \cdot P_{t}\frac{f_{+}(x)}{\lvert \lvert f\rvert \rvert}\leq \lvert \lvert f \rvert \rvert\; \; \text{ since }0\leq\frac{f_{+}(x)}{\lvert \lvert f\rvert \rvert}\leq 1$

Case 1.2 Assume that $f(x)=-f_{-}(x)\leq 0$, then

$0\leq P_{t}f(x) = -P_{t}f_{-}(x)=\lvert \lvert f \rvert \rvert \cdot(- P_{t}\frac{f_{-}(x)}{\lvert \lvert f\rvert \rvert})(*)$ but using the above on this case I would only get $(*)\geq -\lvert \lvert f \rvert \rvert$ which does not help.

Case 2: Assume that $P_{t}f(x)\leq 0$

Case 2.1 Assume that $f(x)=f_{+}(x)\geq 0$, then

$0\geq P_{t}f(x)=P_{t}f_{+}(x)=\lvert \lvert f \rvert \rvert \cdot P_{t}\frac{f_{+}(x)}{\lvert \lvert f\rvert \rvert}\leq \lvert \lvert f \rvert \rvert$ which does not help either.

Case 2.2 Assume that $f(x)=-f_{-}(x)\leq 0$, then

$0\geq P_{t}f(x) = -P_{t}f_{-}(x)=\lvert \lvert f \rvert \rvert \cdot(- P_{t}\frac{f_{-}(x)}{\lvert \lvert f\rvert \rvert})\geq -\lvert \lvert f\rvert\rvert$ which works

So I've been able to cover two of the four cases, any ideas?

Comment: Are you allowed to use Jensen's inequality?

Comment: Be careful with your notation.  Your cases cover the possibilities for the sign of $f(x)$ for a particular $x$, but a general $f$ may be positive at some points and negative at others.  And the value of $(P_t f)(x)$, for some $x$, in general depends on the values of $f$ at all points, not just at $f$.  This is an operator, not composition with another function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your cases are making things more complicated than they need to be.

First, since $P_t$ is linear, we can replace $f$ by $f/\|f\|$ and so reduce to the case $\|f\|=1$.  Now write
$$P_t f = P_t (f_+ - f_-) = P_t f_+ - P_t f_-.$$
Now I claim we have $0 \le P_t f_+ \le 1$ (everywhere, i.e. $0 \le (P_t f_+)(x) \le 1$ for every $x$) and likewise $0 \le P_t f_- \le 1$.  Explain why this is and then complete the proof by showing that $-1 \le P_t f \le 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Idea: Approach by contradiction; suppose there is such an $f$ that violates it, and consider looking at $f' = f_+ + f_-$. Note that $|f| = |f'|$ but, you can show that $|P_t f| \leq |P_t f'| $, which gives $|f'| < |P_t f'|$ for a non-negative function, but that directly contradicts your hypothesis.